# Using UISearchController to search a UITableView in a different View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to implement a `UISearchController` to reference and search for items in a `UITableView` from another View Controller. In other words, I'd like to have search bar in VC1 to search for items in the `UITableView` of VC2.

The reason I'm doing this is because I'd like to have search functionality right when my app opens, i.e. in VC1 instead of having to go VC1->V2 to search for items in VC2.

I have already created some simple code to search for items in the `UITableView` of VC1, but how can I reference the `UITableView` of VC2 instead?

Here's my sample code for `UISearchController` implementation:

```
let tableData = ["One","Two","Three","Twenty-One"]
var filteredTableData = [String]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()

    // Reload the table
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (self.resultSearchController.active && self.resultSearchController.searchBar.text != "") {
        return self.filteredTableData.count
    }
    else {
        return self.tableData.count
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    if (self.resultSearchController.active && self.resultSearchController.searchBar.text != "") {
        filteredTableData = tableData
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (tableData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

FYI: Both my VC1 and VC2 are connected via a `UINavigationController`

Thanks!

Comment: The content you search on the UITableView is just its datasource which is your array of items. Pass or fetch the array to VC1.

Comment: Can you provide sample code please?

Comment: It depends on how your flow is. Is your TableView loaded first or your searchController. If searchController is loaded first do you have the array with you which you are using on TableView. Also how are you displaying data on searchController -TableView?? CustomView??

Comment: Good point to make!...The data from the array in the TableView of VC2 is not loaded until a user selects a cell in TableView of VC1, i.e. not until VC1 segues to VC2....I guess t's obvious that poses a problem in trying to search for data in VC2 from VC1 before it's loaded?....how can I remedy this?

Comment: You definitely have a design problem here. How can you search on a data you doesn't even know which cell user may press. Your VC1 can have n number of cell and based on selection VC2 will be loaded with different sets of n cells. How can you even achieve this. Are you thinking of time travel to future ;) or illustrate your requirement in very detail.